# How to set string resource length limit in Android?

Tags: android, localization, xliff, weblate

It is known that Androd string resources support `xliff` namespace to annotate non-translatable string formatting placeholders, like this

```
    <string name="max_file_size_exceeded_template">File 
         <xliff:g example="some_image.jpg" id="file_name">%1$s</xliff:g>
         is too big and could not be uploaded.</string>
```

It helps translators to undestand what parts of string should not be modified. But sometimes I need to annotate some strings max length it they are used in UI control with limited size. What I want is add text length limit to warn translators about this. Something like `max-length="24" max-lines="2" length-unit="char"` Maybe, xliff supports such thing or it can be achieved in other way.
I use `Weblate` for translations if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this in Weblate, the Andoid format does not support this directly.

- Click on edit (pencil) icon next to flags on the string.
- Enter max-length:LENGTH as check flag.

See also https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/translating.html#additional-information-on-source-strings

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can we hope it will be changed in future and Weblate will be able to parse some relevant params added to `strings.xml`?

Comment: I'm afraid that additional XML parameters would break Android parsing those files. Maybe it could be extracted from the comments though...

Comment: well, I've tried to add some non-existing parameters with xliff namespace and nothing broke. Weblate can have its own namespace and nobody will try to parse it.